# mi codigo de c++ usando do while no funciona

Tags: c++, bucles, while

llevo toda la tarde con este codigo que al momento de pedir al usuario la letra "S" o la "N", no las reconoce o no sabe diferenciarlas, ayuda porfa ademas de aplicar la estructura de un ciclo “infinito” controlado por el usuario.

[image: tiene que salir asi][image: pero termina saliendo de esta manera no importa que letra sea,sale igual]

```
do
{
    cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: "; 
    cin>>registro;
    if(registro[0] != 'n' == registro[0] != 'N')
    {
        cout<<"FIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"desarrollado por: David "<<endl;
        break;
    }
     
}while(registro[0] != 's' == registro[0] != 'S');{
        cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; 
        cin>>referencia;
        cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; 
        cin.ignore(); 
        cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
        cout<<"Digite la talla: "; 
        cin>>talla;
        cout<<"Costo: "; 
        cin>>costo;
        cout<<endl;
}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores con la sintáxis del `do..while` y la lógica de la condición. Puedes probar con algo así:

```
do {
    cout<<"Digite la referencia: "; 
    cin>>referencia;
    cout<<"Digite una descripcion: "; 
    cin.ignore(); 
    cin.getline(descripcion, 30);
    cout<<"Digite la talla: "; 
    cin>>talla;
    cout<<"Costo: "; 
    cin>>costo;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Desea registrar OTRO zapato S/N: "; 
    cin>>registro;
} while(registro[0] == 's' || registro[0] == 'S');

cout<<"FIN DE LA APLICACION "<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"desarrollado por: David "<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```